# React Native push local notification in background(killed)

Tags: react-native

I m coding an application who need push notification in background(app was killed).

its notification app for twitch.

I m store channels with redux persist(asyncstorage).

What should i do? do u have any documentation directly about that ?

Comment: You can use a push notification library like https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification and a background task library like https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch. Then you can call your push notification(s) inside background tasks.

Comment: thx for answer. does it works when app killed?

Comment: Yes it does. One thing to be aware of though is that the minimum interval for a background task being run is 15 minutes. So the interval can only be every 15 minutes or longer.

Comment: i understood thx for answers. i gonna try :) btw u can answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a push notification library like https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification and a background task library like https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch. Then you can call your push notification(s) inside background tasks.

Keep in mind that the minimum interval between background tasks being run is 15 minutes. So the interval can only be 15 minutes or longer.

---

To make this answer more useful, here is a previous implementation I've used to handle push notifications in the background to give you an idea of how to go about it:

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

export default class NotificationService {
  constructor(onRegister, onNotification) {
    this.configure(onRegister, onNotification);
    this.lastId = 0;
  }
  // Handles a user push notification registration
  configure(onRegister, onNotification, gcm = '') {
    PushNotification.configure({
      // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
      onRegister: onRegister,

      // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
      onNotification: onNotification,

      // ANDROID ONLY: GCM Sender ID (optional - not required for local notifications, but is need to receive remote push notifications)
      senderID: gcm,

      /**
       * (optional) default: true
       * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
       * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
       */
      requestPermissions: true,
    });
  }
  // Send a direct push notification to the user
  localNotif() {
    this.lastId++;
    PushNotification.localNotification({
      /* Android Only Properties */
      id: '' + this.lastId,
      bigText: 'My big text that will be shown when notification is expanded',
      subText: 'This is a subText',

      /* iOS and Android properties */
      title: 'Local Notification',
      message: 'My Notification Message',
      actions: '["Yes", "No"]', // (Android only) See the doc for notification actions to know more
    });
  }

  // Schedules a push notification by a given javascript Date object
  scheduleNotif(date, title, message) {
    this.lastId++;
    PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
      date: date,

      /* Android Only Properties */
      id: '' + this.lastId,
      bigText: '',
      subText: '',

      /* iOS and Android properties */
      title: title,
      message: message,
    });
  }

  checkPermission(cbk) {
    return PushNotification.checkPermissions(cbk);
  }

  cancelNotif() {
    PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: '' + this.lastId });
  }

  cancelAll() {
    PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
  }
}
```

```
// ...
import BackgroundFetch from 'react-native-background-fetch';


const initBackGroundFetch = () => {
  BackgroundFetch.configure(
    {
      minimumFetchInterval: 15, // <-- minutes (15 is minimum allowed)
      // Android options
      forceAlarmManager: false, // <-- Set true to bypass JobScheduler.
      stopOnTerminate: false,
      startOnBoot: true,
      requiredNetworkType: BackgroundFetch.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY, // Network connection needed
    },
    async taskId => {
      // Do stuff with notifications, for example:
      const notificationService = new NotificationService(
         () => {//... what to do on register},
         () => {//... what to do on notification }
      )
      const date = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 1000) // adjust according to your use case
      notificationService.scheduleNotif(date, "title", "message");
      BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
    },
    error => {
      console.log('[js] RNBackgroundFetch failed to start');
    },
  );
};

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
     initBackGroundFetch();
  }, []);

  return (
    // ...
  );
};
```

The `NotificationService` is an adjusted version of an example the react native push notification library provides found here: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/example/NotifService.js.

Comment: should i use setinterval in it ? or its already scheduled for 15 min ?

Comment: It is already scheduled for every 15 minutes using `minimumFetchInterval: 15`.

Comment: oh it works when app in foreground but when terminate. it doesnt work :( should i do otherwhise ? should i set true that => https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch#config-boolean-enableheadless-false

Comment: You could also try to schedule the notification when the app is running. Then terminate the app and see if the notification still pops up https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#scheduled-notifications.